# Flex 4.0 HMAC.hash binary data

Tags: php, apache-flex, binary, cryptography, hmac

I have the following PHP code, which I need to get working in Flex 4.0:

```
$mac = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $message, $secret, true));
```

If the last element is a true the `hash_hmac` is outputted as raw binary data, if it is false outputs lowercase hexits.

I have the following code written in Flex:

```
encryptedString = HMAC.hash(tempString,message,algorithm);
```

However, it outputs it as lowercase hexit. I can not find out how to convert the Flex output to binary data to match the PHP.

Does anyone know?

Comment: What is HMAC? It is not a Flex Framework class.

Comment: I am using the following import statements in flex:

import com.adobe.crypto.HMAC;
import com.adobe.crypto.SHA256;